# can store tiles attribute value in jsp varible

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, tiles

I use Tiles with spring-mvc in my project

I Want to tiles attribute value store jsp page variable can this is possible

like this

```
<c:out value="<tiles:insertAttribute name='title'/>"></c:out>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following code to i get my question solution

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="title"/>
<c:out value="${title}"/>
```